# Is it possible to read Binary data from SQL Server outside (using other prog environments)

Tags: sql-server, binary, hex

I use SQL Server 2005.  I wanted to know if it is even possible to read binary data printed from SQL-Server in other environments such as Matlab?

For example,

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
CREATE TABLE #Temp ( C1 binary ) INSERT INTO #Temp (C1) SELECT 100

SELECT * FROM #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

The result is `0x64` which I believe is hexadecimal notation.  This data when viewed using notepad looks the same.  However, a binary 100 written from Matlab when opened in notepad is definitely not hexadecimal!  Please help/comment!

Comment: You could improve the question by explaining what you are trying to do.  How does the data look in SQL Server (post table definition.)  How are you trying to access it from Matlab?

Comment: @Andomar Thanks. I have edited it now.  My main Q is whether it is even possible to do it or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to read binary output from SQL Server in other tools, given they handle binary input.

From what you've written, you're not comparing things in an equivalent way (apples-to-apples). Hexadecimal is just one way of representing the bits in human-sensible form, so unless your viewing methods are both capable of using the same notation, you'll probably see different things.  I'm pretty sure Notepad doesn't do hex.

The SSMS "output" of 0x64 is the tool's way of representing binary data - in this case, decimal value 100 - in print/on screen. If you cut & paste from the SSMS window, you're actually cutting the text string "0x64", so opening that in Notepad will *look* the same, but it's not in actuality your original decimal 100 value.

If you're saving a file from Matlab & opening that in Notepad, you should see the byte value(s) interpreted as text, probably 'd' (lower-case "D") in this case since that's the ASCII/UTF-8 value for decimal 100.

Comment: You are right. Thanks.  But how do I print the binary data from SSMS? I can do the simple 'output-to-file' and give the file extension as .bin?

Comment: You're going to have to write to a file, not "print". If you're in SSMS, right-click in the query pane, select Results To -> Results To File, then run your query. You should get a standard Windows 'Save' dialog where you can tell your system where to put the file. The file name extension doesn't really matter as long as you and the other program won't get confused.

If you're using SQLCMD, you can use output redirection (">") to create a file.

Or you can use the bcp utility.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually using the very same `File` option with extension as .bin.  You have already said that extension doesn't matter.  My problem is I'm unable to read this data in Matlab.  I get some weird answers.  I have tried almost all the `precisions` at http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fread.html

Comment: What kind of wierd answers? You may need to output formatted text in something like a .csv file to move data into Matlab from SQL Server.  Can you have your Matlab use SQL Server as a data source directly? (I know next to nothing about Matlab)

Comment: I can directly connect to SQLServer, then create a .csv/.txt and read it in Matlab. It is easy to do and I have been doing it for quite some time. But it is slow and has some other issues.  My best hope is to write a binary file in SQL and read it in Matlab. However, I cannot find any explicit help/info regarding this.  My data is always `INT` or `FLOAT` in SQL Server.  As per your reply, I am now saving the output in a file without any extension and I'm trying to read it in Matlab.  It seems as if I should be able to read it.

Comment: For the record, my main Q is here: My main Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302613/write-a-binary-file-from-sql-server2005-and-read-it-in-matlab  Thanks DaveE.